# Problem with jQuery nav menu causing unexpected page behavior when using focus() and click() together

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have six dots(images) and text which animates focus and text glow on click respectively 
 ( https://ibb.co/sjQ7C00 )
so I applied this jquery which focus on dot/image and click on text automatically on page load.

```
$(function() {
    $("#img1").click();
});

$(function() {
    $("#img1").focus();
});
```

The problem is when I use this jquery code it works the way it is supposed to be but it opens page in the middle like directly where click happens ( https://ibb.co/VVb4D4j ) where as it supposed to be opening on top of the page when I don't use this jquery code animation don't happen on page load

With jquery code ( https://ibb.co/sjQ7C00 )
without jquery code ( https://ibb.co/RhVDGfH )

```js
$('.paralx-dot-1').on('click', function () {
    $(this).transition({ scale: 1.8 });
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('img').transition({ scale: 1 });
});
```

```html
<ul class="paralx-position">
    <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="2">Accelerate</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div2" id="img2" tabindex="0"></img></li>
    <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="3">Transform</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div3" id="img3" tabindex="0"></img></li>
    <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="1">Build</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" class="Active" data-box="div1"  id="img1"  tabindex="0"><span class="icon-position"><!--<img src="images/logos/noun_build_1909132.svg" class="icon"></img></span></img>--></li>
    <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="4">Ignite</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div4" id="img4"  tabindex="0"></img></li>
    <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="5">Develop</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div5" id="img5" tabindex="0"></img></li>
    <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="6">Engineer</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div6" id="img6" tabindex="0"></img></li>
</ul>
```

I couldn't find alternative to this jquery code( focus , click ) as I am new to JavaScript and jquery.

Comment: So the problem is the page grows in size and causes a scrollbar? Would making the dots `position:absolute` help? Or if the growth isn't too much, you could use `overflow:hidden` on the page. Also, `img` does not require a closing tag.

Comment: Also, if you look at your `<span>` with a class of "icon-position", you'll see you missed a closing `</span>` tag. Don't know if that's related... but it's there.

Comment: animation happens as it supposed to be when used ( focus and click ) jquery code but it opens page directly in middle ( https://ibb.co/VVb4D4j ) where as it supposed to be opening where page starts top ( https://ibb.co/4RZXG9z ) 

when i don't use ( focus and click ) jquery page open at top but animation don't happen but when i use ( focus and click ) jquery  animation happen but page open in middle

Comment: that <span> was just for some experiment which was closed and in comment .. that's not causing the problem

Comment: Ok. I think I get it. In this picture -  https://ibb.co/VVb4D4j  - you want the words "What we do" and the content below it to start from the top of the page and not from the (vertical) center point?

Comment: @Christopher Bennett - thank-you so much for help but i sorted it out 
the problem was i was using ( focus and click ) both where as only click() worked the same way it supposed to be without using focus() and page opens where it supposed to be and animation happen as it supposed to be.

Comment: No problem. That's something I now know for the future. Glad you solved it. Would it be ok with you if I edit the wording of your question to make it easier for others to find?

Comment: @Christopher Bennett - i was talking about (Build-Accelerate-Transform).
again thank-you for helping.

Comment: yeah go on edit it. @Christopher Bennett

Comment: How about "Problem with jQuery nav menu causing unexpected page behavior when using `focus()` and `click()`"?

Comment: done. Hope people will find it useful ;-)